# W3 Failing with <noscript> nested in a DIV tag

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I've got my application working great, however I'd LOVE to be able to have it validate completely on W3.

My problem is quite simple.  I'm using the Bing JS API to attach a Bing Map to a Div tag.  Within that Div tag, I have a `<noscript>` element that calls the MultiMap static map provider IF javascript is disabled.  The reason I've chosen to do it this way is because I don't want to call the MultiMap API if I'm not going to actually use it.

Is there an alternative way to do this so that I can be W3 HTML5 valid?

```
<div id='bingMap' class="largeMap">
    <noscript>
        <img src="http://developer.multimap.com/API/map/1.2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?zoomFactor=11&amp;width=550&amp;height=400&amp;lat_1=51.18468&amp;lon_1=-114.497999&amp;lat_2=51.169858&amp;lon_2=-114.32549&amp;lat_3=51.083277&amp;lon_3=-114.203964&amp;lat_4=51.063097&amp;lon_4=-114.092031&amp;lat_5=50.939664&amp;lon_5=-113.973568" />
    </noscript>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't obsess over making every single page 100% W3C validator-compliant. If it works on every browser in your target audience, one little `<noscript>` isn't the end of the world.

Comment: That's what I keep telling myself, but I'm a perfectionist, so it sorta bugs me :-P

Comment: Don't listen to them, your problem is easily fixed by adding a div wrapper around the image (and adding an alt to it.)

Answer (score 1):

This perhaps:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("<" + "!--");
  </script>
  <p>This will be commented out if scripting is supported.</p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("-" + "->");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This appears as though it would work, however I would prefer `<span class="cS"></span>This will be commented out<span class="cE"></span>` and use jQuery to inject the comment symbols.  Just looks cleaner than having inline script blocks.

Comment: That won't work because jQuery won't run until the DOM is loaded, and by then multimap will have been referenced. That's why I opted for the script to be run as the DOM is being created.

Comment: cool I have used the solution. Only one doubt why you concatinated "<" and "!--"?. I had to change "<" to "&gt;" to validate HTML

Answer (score 1):

wrap the `<img/>` into a div, p or another block-element. `<noscript>` is only allowed to have block-elements as direct child.

```
<div id='bingMap' class="largeMap">
    <noscript>
        <div>
            <img src="....." />
        </div>
    </noscript>
</div>
```

Comment: The img tag also needs an alt to validate

Comment: I was hoping you were right, but the error actually says ***XHTML element noscript not allowed as child of XHTML element div in this context*** (Yes I tested it.)

Comment: Weird, when I put it into the validator it passes. I'll post example code as an answer in a second

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking out the xmlns in order to prevent it from interpreting your code as XHTML5 (as opposed to HTML5) as XHTML5 is just a stricter version of HTML5 disallowing many features. HTML5 still supports XHTML-style tags, so no loss.

Something like the following would work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bingMap" class="largeMap">
      <noscript>
        <img alt="" src="http://developer.multimap.com/API/map/1.2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?zoomFactor=11&amp;width=550&amp;height=400&amp;lat_1=51.18468&amp;lon_1=-114.497999&amp;lat_2=51.169858&amp;lon_2=-114.32549&amp;lat_3=51.083277&amp;lon_3=-114.203964&amp;lat_4=51.063097&amp;lon_4=-114.092031&amp;lat_5=50.939664&amp;lon_5=-113.973568" />
      </noscript>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following validates for me at http://validator.w3.org/check

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
<title>title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id='bingMap' class="largeMap">
    <noscript>
      <div>
        <img alt="" src="http://developer.multimap.com/API/map/1.2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?zoomFactor=11&amp;width=550&amp;height=400&amp;lat_1=51.18468&amp;lon_1=-114.497999&amp;lat_2=51.169858&amp;lon_2=-114.32549&amp;lat_3=51.083277&amp;lon_3=-114.203964&amp;lat_4=51.063097&amp;lon_4=-114.092031&amp;lat_5=50.939664&amp;lon_5=-113.973568" />
      </div>
    </noscript>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: however, I'm building in HTML5, so although yours is valid... for some reason, mine is not.

Comment: Your original question said xhtml ><

Comment: sorry, must have been typing too fast without paying closer attention.  I corrected it.